# Calcluate and insert financial years with its financial period, month, start and end date for 20 years

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I need to generate dates data in my database for 20 years. It should calculate financial start month (suppose July 2019) and then calculate the start date (July 1) and end date (July 31) and period of the financial year(period of 7). Then it should find all months incrementing from July for 20 years.

It should be like this

financial_year  month period    start_date     end_date

1. 2019            July   07       2019/07/01     2019/07/31
2. 2019            AUGUST 08       2019/08/01     2019/08/31
3. ....
4. ....
5. 2039

Can anybody help me how can I solve this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: What problem?  All you did was rattle off some parameters.  What have you tried? What were the failure points?  You'll also want to explain things like `period of 7` means...are there 7 financial periods in the year?? It doesnt seem like it could be the 7th period as you said  July was the start month

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I am looking for the possible solutions. I could not decide how to solve this issue that's why asking for help. I could not decide if this can be done in SQL only or need something extra.

Comment: You want to do this in C# or SQL? Did you try any thing? What problem you are facing in that? Hint. Take start date as 01 July and use DateTime.AddMonths to get start date of next month. Use looping to do this repeatedly

Comment: Try a little internet search next time. Here is one discussion of building a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you for the logic. I am doing the same logic to generate the dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @year int, @month int
SELECT @year = 2019, @month = 7

;with cte as (
    SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, 1) start_date, 1 as cnt
    union all 
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, start_date), cnt + 1
    FROM cte
    WHERE cnt < 240
),
cte2 as (
    SELECT start_date, 
        DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, start_date)) end_date,
        DATEPART(YEAR, start_date) year, 
        DATENAME(MONTH, start_date) month,
        DATEPART(MONTH, start_date) period  
    FROM cte
)
select year, month, 
    RIGHT('0' + cast(period as varchar(2)), 2) as period,
    start_date, 
    end_date
from cte2
option(maxrecursion 0)
```

Returns:

```
year    month       period  start_date  end_date
2019    July        07      2019-07-01  2019-07-31
2019    August      08      2019-08-01  2019-08-31
2019    September   09      2019-09-01  2019-09-30
...
2039    April       04      2039-04-01  2039-04-30
2039    May         05      2039-05-01  2039-05-31
2039    June        06      2039-06-01  2039-06-30
```